# How to make valgrind ignore certain line?

Tags: c, valgrind

for example

```
==26460== 2 bytes in 1 blocks are still reachable in loss record 2 of 105
==26460==    at 0x4C28BE3: malloc (vg_replace_malloc.c:299)
==26460==    by 0x580D889: strdup (in /usr/lib64/libc-2.17.so)
==26460==    by 0x4F50AF: init (init.c:468)
==26460==    by 0x406D75: main (main.c:825)
```

I want to not check init.c:468: `mode = strdup`, i'm sure this only malloc once, and will last whole process life.

Is it possible to make valgrind not check this line?

Comment: Why do you want to manipulate the output of valgrind? I would not care about "possible". I recommend not to. Either fix whatever valgrind complains about or live with the fact that it complains about something.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As I said in my comment: I recommend not to.

But Valgrind does have a feature to suppress warnings.
The most convenient way of suppressing a specific message is supported by the feature dedicated to exactly that purpose:

```
--gen-suppressions=yes
```

Which apparently will ouptput the precise suppression syntax for each/any generated message.

See 5.1 in the FAQ:
http://valgrind.org/docs/manual/faq.html#faq.writesupp

*(I love their style:

"F:Can you write ... for me?" and I expected a totally adequate

"A:No." But they actually answer

"A: Yes ...". Beyond cool.)*

Answer (score 1):

You should fix the leaks; it is far better to do so.

You can't stop Valgrind checking for the leaks, but you can stop it reporting them by suppressing the leaks.

Use:

```
valgrind --gen-suppressions=yes --leak-check=all -- tested-program …
```

You can then save the suppressions in a file, say `tp.suppressions`, and subsequently you use:

```
valgrind --suppressions=tp.suppressions -- tested-program …
```

If you work on a Mac like I do, and work with bleeding edge systems, you'll often find it necessary to suppress leaks from the system startup code — memory that's allocated before `main()` is called and which you cannot therefore control.

OTOH, it is routine that after the new release of macOS, it takes a while to get Valgrind running again.  I upgraded to macOS High Sierra 10.13; Valgrind has stopped working again because the kernel isn't recognized.