# How to use thrust and valgrind together to detect memory leaks?

Tags: c++, memory-leaks, cuda, valgrind, thrust

**Is there a way to use the CUDA thrust library with the Valgrind memory leak checker?**

The reason I ask is because this simple program:

```
#include <thrust/device_vector.h>

int main(){
    thrust::device_vector<int> D(5);
    assert( D.size() == 5 );
}
```

compiled with:

```sh
$ /usr/local/cuda-11.1/bin/nvcc device_vector.cu -o device_vector.cu.x
```

Makes Valgrind believe that there are multiple possible memory leaks.

**I know they must be false positives and that valgrind is not made to detect GPU memory leaks but I wonder if there is a flag or a standard way to make both tools work together (e.g. to detect CPU memory leaks).**

If there is a standard set of Valgrind exceptions around I will gladly use them, but I wanted to ask before playing wack-a-mole.

```sh
$ valgrind ./device_vector.cu.x 
==765561== Memcheck, a memory error detector
==765561== Copyright (C) 2002-2017, and GNU GPL'd, by Julian Seward et al.
==765561== Using Valgrind-3.15.0 and LibVEX; rerun with -h for copyright info
==765561== Command: ./device_vector.cu.x
==765561== 
==765561== Warning: noted but unhandled ioctl 0x30000001 with no size/direction hints.
==765561==    This could cause spurious value errors to appear.
==765561==    See README_MISSING_SYSCALL_OR_IOCTL for guidance on writing a proper wrapper.
==765561== Warning: noted but unhandled ioctl 0x27 with no size/direction hints.
==765561==    This could cause spurious value errors to appear.
==765561==    See README_MISSING_SYSCALL_OR_IOCTL for guidance on writing a proper wrapper.
==765561== Warning: noted but unhandled ioctl 0x25 with no size/direction hints.
==765561==    This could cause spurious value errors to appear.
==765561==    See README_MISSING_SYSCALL_OR_IOCTL for guidance on writing a proper wrapper.
==765561== Warning: noted but unhandled ioctl 0x37 with no size/direction hints.
==765561==    This could cause spurious value errors to appear.
==765561==    See README_MISSING_SYSCALL_OR_IOCTL for guidance on writing a proper wrapper.
==765561== Warning: noted but unhandled ioctl 0x17 with no size/direction hints.
==765561==    This could cause spurious value errors to appear.
==765561==    See README_MISSING_SYSCALL_OR_IOCTL for guidance on writing a proper wrapper.
==765561== Warning: set address range perms: large range [0x200000000, 0x300200000) (noaccess)
==765561== Warning: set address range perms: large range [0x681f000, 0x2681e000) (noaccess)
==765561== Warning: noted but unhandled ioctl 0x19 with no size/direction hints.
==765561==    This could cause spurious value errors to appear.
==765561==    See README_MISSING_SYSCALL_OR_IOCTL for guidance on writing a proper wrapper.
==765561== Warning: set address range perms: large range [0x10006000000, 0x10106000000) (noaccess)
==765561== Warning: noted but unhandled ioctl 0x49 with no size/direction hints.
==765561==    This could cause spurious value errors to appear.
==765561==    See README_MISSING_SYSCALL_OR_IOCTL for guidance on writing a proper wrapper.
==765561== Warning: noted but unhandled ioctl 0x21 with no size/direction hints.
==765561==    This could cause spurious value errors to appear.
==765561==    See README_MISSING_SYSCALL_OR_IOCTL for guidance on writing a proper wrapper.
==765561== Warning: noted but unhandled ioctl 0x1b with no size/direction hints.
==765561==    This could cause spurious value errors to appear.
==765561==    See README_MISSING_SYSCALL_OR_IOCTL for guidance on writing a proper wrapper.
==765561== Warning: noted but unhandled ioctl 0x44 with no size/direction hints.
==765561==    This could cause spurious value errors to appear.
==765561==    See README_MISSING_SYSCALL_OR_IOCTL for guidance on writing a proper wrapper.
==765561== 
==765561== HEAP SUMMARY:
==765561==     in use at exit: 6,678,624 bytes in 8,647 blocks
==765561==   total heap usage: 11,448 allocs, 2,801 frees, 40,718,174 bytes allocated
==765561== 
==765561== LEAK SUMMARY:
==765561==    definitely lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==765561==    indirectly lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==765561==      possibly lost: 22,216 bytes in 187 blocks
==765561==    still reachable: 6,656,408 bytes in 8,460 blocks
==765561==         suppressed: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==765561== Rerun with --leak-check=full to see details of leaked memory
==765561== 
==765561== For lists of detected and suppressed errors, rerun with: -s
==765561== ERROR SUMMARY: 0 errors from 0 contexts (suppressed: 0 from 0)
```

The mentioned readme [README_MISSING_SYSCALL_OR_IOCTL](http://cs.swan.ac.uk/%7Ecsoliver/ok-sat-library/internet_html/doc/doc/Valgrind/3.8.1/html/dist.readme-missing.html) was not very helpful to me.

---

**NOTE ADDED**: CUDA comes with a memchecker called `cuda-memcheck` which doesn't report memory leaks in the program above, however it doesn't seem to be a replacement for valgrind, since it doesn't detect the actual memory leak in a simple cpu program:

```
#include <thrust/device_vector.h>

int main(){
//  thrust::device_vector<int> D(5);
//  assert( D.size() == 5 );
    
//  cudaDeviceSynchronize();
    std::allocator<int> alloc;
    int* p = alloc.allocate(10);
    p[0] = 2;
    return p[0];
}
```

Comment: `cuda-memcheck` leak check facility pertains to device code, not host code.  So it is not surprising that it doesn't identify host code leaks.  It is certainly not a replacement for valgrind.  valgrind works on host code.  `cuda-memcheck` works on device code.  And by that I am not suggesting that is the only difference or that they are otherwise feature identical.

Comment: Can you find out what these ioctls are and if they need any special handling?

Comment: I can run with full details and show the result. @PaulFloyd I don’t understand the instructions in the readme.

Comment: @RobertCrovella I understand, a program combining cpu and gpu allocations in principle needs testing with both cuda-memcheck and valgrind. I just wonder why nvcc and thrust generate these false positives and if there is a stand workaround.

Comment: If you want to add Valgrind support for these ioctls you need to know what the ioctls do. If you don't know what they do then the best that you can do is to treat them as a no-op and hope that is sufficient. These are not false positives. Valgrind is not saying that there are errors, just that it does not recognize these ioctls.

Comment: This has nothing to do with `nvcc` and very little to do with thrust. It has to do with the CUDA runtime API (and/or CUDA driver API) libraries, which interact directly with the host operating system as well as the GPU driver.  In this context, ioctls and syscalls are expected and "normal".  I'm not saying these calls or libraries are pristine; bugs are always possible.   As indicated above, valgrind considers such as "unhandled" or "unrecognized" (by valgrind, unless suitable wrappers are provided).  So the output at least to some degree is "normal".  Again, no claims regarding defects.

Comment: @RobertCrovella, what is the canonical way to go forward. Does the cuda team tend to register these special calls with valgrind eventually? I know how to make valgrind exceptions, but this seems to be more fundamental.

Comment: I don't know of anything canonical.  As I mentioned, I think most of these are coming from usage of the CUDA runtime API library.  You could [file a bug](https://forums.developer.nvidia.com/t/how-to-report-a-bug/67911) at developer.nvidia.com requesting some sort of action to address these, don't know what that would be exactly.  For a shorter term approach, maybe [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46482390/how-to-make-valgrind-ignore-certain-line).

Comment: @RobertCrovella, thanks I generated a suppression file for this problem (see my answer). It seems that these are ultimately related by indirect calls to `malloc` and `calloc` (yes, both, depending on the case) by `cudaMalloc`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Currently I am using this suppression file `.valgrind-supressions` at the root of my project:

```
{
   <suppression_for_thrust_allocations>
   Memcheck:Leak
   match-leak-kinds: possible
   fun:*alloc
   ...
   obj:*libcuda.so.*
   ...
   obj:*libcuda.so.*
   fun:__cudart*
   ...
   fun:__cudart*
   fun:cudaMalloc
   fun:_ZN6thrust6system4cuda6detail20cuda_memory_resourceIXadL_Z10cudaMallocEEXadL_Z8cudaFreeEENS_8cuda_cub7pointerIvEEE11do_allocateEmm
   ...
}
```

(the three dots are actual code)

By removing the `_ZN6thrust` line maybe it could be more general, but I don't want to generalize suppressions prematurely.

It is important to note that this is not checking for leaks in the GPU, for that `cuda-memcheck` is needed.

---

UPDATE: I broadened the suppression to 1) include cases generated from `cudaMallocManaged` as well 2) Caused by CUDA runtime without the participation of thrust allocators (as @RobertCrovella mentioned).

```
{
   <suppression_for_cudaMalloc_and_cudaMallocManaged_allocations>
   Memcheck:Leak
   match-leak-kinds: possible
   fun:*alloc
   ...
   obj:*libcuda.so.*
   ...
   obj:*libcuda.so.*
   fun:__cudart*
   ...
   fun:__cudart*
   fun:cudaMalloc*
   ...
}
```

---

In `CMakeLists.txt` I am using these options to actually use the suppression file listed above

```
  ...
set(MEMORYCHECK_COMMAND_OPTIONS "-q --tool=memcheck --leak-check=yes --num-callers=52 --trace-children=yes --leak-check=full --track-origins=yes --gen-suppressions=all") # must go before `include(CTest)`
set(MEMORYCHECK_SUPPRESSIONS_FILE "${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/.valgrind-suppressions") # must go before `include(CTest)`

include(CTest)
  ...
```

(the three dots here stand for the rest of the file)

Improvements to this suppression pattern are welcome.

---

For reference a full automatically generated suppression by `valgrind` looks like this:

```
{
   <insert_a_suppression_name_here>
   Memcheck:Leak
   match-leak-kinds: possible
   fun:calloc
   obj:/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcuda.so.470.63.01
   obj:/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcuda.so.470.63.01
   obj:/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcuda.so.470.63.01
   obj:/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcuda.so.470.63.01
   obj:/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcuda.so.470.63.01
   obj:/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcuda.so.470.63.01
   obj:/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcuda.so.470.63.01
   obj:/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcuda.so.470.63.01
   obj:/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcuda.so.470.63.01
   obj:/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcuda.so.470.63.01
   obj:/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcuda.so.470.63.01
   obj:/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcuda.so.470.63.01
   obj:/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcuda.so.470.63.01
   obj:/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcuda.so.470.63.01
   fun:__cudart764
   fun:__cudart763
   fun:__cudart768
   fun:__cudart941
   fun:__cudart607
   fun:cudaMalloc
   fun:_ZN6thrust6system4cuda6detail20cuda_memory_resourceIXadL_Z10cudaMallocEEXadL_Z8cudaFreeEENS_8cuda_cub7pointerIvEEE11do_allocateEmm
   fun:_ZN6thrust26device_ptr_memory_resourceINS_6system4cuda6detail20cuda_memory_resourceIXadL_Z10cudaMallocEEXadL_Z8cudaFreeEENS_8cuda_cub7pointerIvEEEEE11do_allocateEmm
   fun:_ZN6thrust2mr9allocatorIiNS_26device_ptr_memory_resourceINS_6system4cuda6detail20cuda_memory_resourceIXadL_Z10cudaMallocEEXadL_Z8cudaFreeEENS_8cuda_cub7pointerIvEEEEEEE8allocateEm
   fun:_ZZN6thrust6detail16allocator_traitsINS_16device_allocatorIiEEE8allocateERS3_mEN19workaround_warnings8allocateES5_m
   fun:_ZN6thrust6detail16allocator_traitsINS_16device_allocatorIiEEE8allocateERS3_m
   fun:_ZN6thrust6detail18contiguous_storageIiNS_16device_allocatorIiEEE8allocateEm
   fun:_ZN6thrust6detail11vector_baseIiNS_16device_allocatorIiEEE17allocate_and_copyINS0_15normal_iteratorIPKiEEEEvmT_SA_RNS0_18contiguous_storageIiS3_EE
   fun:_ZN6thrust6detail11vector_baseIiNS_16device_allocatorIiEEE10range_initINS0_15normal_iteratorIPKiEEEEvT_SA_NS_27random_access_traversal_tagE
   fun:_ZN6thrust6detail11vector_baseIiNS_16device_allocatorIiEEE10range_initINS0_15normal_iteratorIPKiEEEEvT_SA_
   fun:_ZN6thrust6detail11vector_baseIiNS_16device_allocatorIiEEEC1IiSaIiEEERKNS1_IT_T0_EE
   fun:_ZN6thrust13device_vectorIiNS_16device_allocatorIiEEEC1IiSaIiEEERKNS_11host_vectorIT_T0_EE
   fun:_ZN6vector11test_methodEv
   fun:_ZL14vector_invokerv
   fun:_ZN5boost6detail8function22void_function_invoker0IPFvvEvE6invokeERNS1_15function_bufferE
   obj:/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libboost_unit_test_framework.so.1.74.0
   fun:_ZN5boost17execution_monitor13catch_signalsERKNS_8functionIFivEEE
   fun:_ZN5boost17execution_monitor7executeERKNS_8functionIFivEEE
   fun:_ZN5boost17execution_monitor8vexecuteERKNS_8functionIFvvEEE
   fun:_ZN5boost9unit_test19unit_test_monitor_t21execute_and_translateERKNS_8functionIFvvEEEm
   obj:/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libboost_unit_test_framework.so.1.74.0
   obj:/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libboost_unit_test_framework.so.1.74.0
   fun:_ZN5boost9unit_test9framework3runEmb
   fun:_ZN5boost9unit_test14unit_test_mainEPFbvEiPPc
   fun:main
}
```